# FB Blocked Link to Facebook Authentication

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, facebook-authentication

For the first stage in our application, the user must "continue with Facebook" for us to pull certain permissions. Today users tried to create an account and are experiencing the screenshot attached. Facebook blocked this URL: https://dandy-user-pool-prod.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/idresponse

[SCREENSHOT HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYazz.jpg)

How can we fix this? Not sure what's wrong as this URL has been working fine to allow users to create an account for the past month.

Comment: We have confirmed this is currently an issue.  We have reached out to Facebook to see why they have started blocking these urls.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try now? The block has been lifted.